# Python interpeter that randomly changes type or varrible

Tags: python, compiler-errors

So I am learning python for fun and I have come across an error that completely stumps me. When I am running my code I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'type'
```

this error is triggered by the division in:

```
for i in items:
    print i[1]
    multiplier = WeightLeft / i[1]
```

the thing that has me so confused is that when i print i[1] it prints

```
<type 'int>
```

I tried to force the denominator to be an int by putting int(i[1]) as the denominator but i get a new error:

```
TypeError: descriptor '__trunc__' of 'int' object needs an argument
```

Any advice someone could give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should add more of the missing code to the question. There isn't enough context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i[1]` is the type object `int`, not an instance of this type.  Trying to convert this type object to an integer is like calling `int(int)`.

Comment: ok thank you, it was how I instantiating the tuple that I held the data in which caused the error

Answer (score 1):

`<type 'int'>` is what you'd get if you do `i[1] = int`, so I'm guessing that somewhere you have `i[1] = int` instead of `i[1] = int(...)`.